# how to map non-standard table with ActiveRecord or should I use other ORM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using a tool(UltraSms) that required three tables named (smsin, smsout & smsparts)

I need these tables to be used in the same Rails application that has other tables. With ActiveRecrod I know that table names has to be plural of the Active record class name by convention. Is there a way to map those to an ActiveRecrod class easily or should I find manual way to do ORM for it?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "smsin"
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Seems that in Rails3.1 , the method name changed to `table_name=`, e.g.

```
class Mouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "mice"
end
```