# Change the Rails db naming rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

As we know,when I execute the order

```
rails g model member
```

I will get a model named `member` and a db migrate to create a table named `members`

But now,I want the table to be named `member`,just the same with the model.

Somewhere I can config this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938413/how-to-map-non-standard-table-with-activerecord-or-should-i-use-other-orm

Comment: You want to change it now that you’ve generated it? Or you want to change all future generated tables?

Comment: Yes,I just want to config the rule,so that I can change all future generated tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/application.rb`, add:

```
config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false
```

See the complete documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html.

If you can get away with using plural table names, I recommend you just stick with them. Not all plugins play nice with this setting, especially those with custom generators. They sometimes assume you've gone with the Rails convention.

One of the worst conventions in Rails, in my opinion, but life is easier when you don't fight with Rails's assumptions.